# Jedis sending QUIT request to redis server internally

Tags: kotlin, redis, jedis

My Jedis client sending the `quit` request internally causing the Redis server to close the connection.
This is unexpected behavior.
Below is the tcpdump of my host.

```
QUIT

17:12:17.702322 IP SOURCE_HOST.29039 > DEST_HOST.34250: Flags [P.], seq 1290557:1290562, ack 833190, win 65160, options [nop,nop,TS val 346069381 ecr 351399090], length 5
E..98\@.;...
%V.
W..qo....
.P.l.....U......
........+OK

17:12:17.702345 IP DEST_HOST.34250 > SOURCE_HOST.29039: Flags [.], ack 1290562, win 65366, options [nop,nop,TS val 351399092 ecr 346069381], length 0
E..4..@.@..l
```

I am doing following operations. 
1. get() 
2. set() 
3. setex() 
4. ping() 
5. del() 
6. keys()

I am using Jedis: 2.9.3 with Kotlin. 
Operation: Get the resource(connection) from JedisPool and send a request(ex. get()). 
Does anyone have an idea why Jedis sends `QUIT` request without calling it explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JedisPool uses JedisFactory.
2. `destroyObject` in JedisFactory calls `quit`.
3. `destroyObject` of JedisFactory actually overrides `destroyObject` of PooledObjectFactory.
4. GenericObjectPool uses PooledObjectFactory.
5. `destroy` in GenericObjectPool calls `destroyObject` of PooledObjectFactory.

   - (and so `destroyObject` of JedisFactory) which results in a calling of `quit`.

There are many cases where `destroy` of GenericObjectPool is get called.

Comment: thank you. It has really helped to understand. It looks like there is no way to stop sending this `QUIT` signal.